# What is the Java API for setting a parameter in the AWS Parameter store?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We are using the following code to get parameters from the AWS  Parameter Store:

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().build();
    GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest();
    request.setWithDecryption(true);
    request.setPath(path);
    GetParametersByPathResult result = client.getParametersByPath(request);
```

What is the code to set Parameters?

Answer (score 6):

You can create keys this way:

```
//Instantiate default ssm client
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();   

//Create request object with the key and value in String
PutParameterRequest putRequest = new PutParameterRequest();
putRequest.setName(<key as String>);
putRequest.setValue(<value as String>);
putRequest.setType("String");

//Overwrite the key if it already exist
putRequest.setOverwrite(true);
ssmClient.putParameter(putRequest);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer my help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set custom query parameters you can use,

**putCustomQueryParameter**

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest.html#putCustomQueryParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please show the whole code?  In particular, how can  I create  AmazonWebServiceRequest?